# How to cut an Image on inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

#### How to remove a shape from an image?

It's a simple question but also googling it I can't find a solution.

| Image to explain the problem | Image I'll have to do |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Fuckuimage] | [image: center] |

**Concentrate attentions** to the **Image to explain the problem**
As a result I would like to have two circles,

- One black
- And one green
  **PS**: The green one will be cut with the shape that is in the center.

How can I achieve this?
It's simply but I don't know how to make it

<sub>Ps:
if you think this question is *useful* and *well written*, do not hesitate to put an **upvote**, *thanks*</sub>

Comment: Excuse me but do you want a) a transparent hole to the coffin shaped area or b) should it be differently colored or c) is there some magic reason why the coffin shape should be filled with that green shape which already has been in the green ellipse inside he black circle(= no other green taken from elsewhere with same RGB numbers are valid for those magic reasons)? Shortly: the meaning of term cut is unknown.

Comment: Yes, a transparent hole to the coffin shaped area in the green circle the a) question

Comment: I will have to do exactly the same thing for the next image that you can see in the question, i.e. remove that piece of color between the two cables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select those shapes under the coffin which need the hole, group them. Then select the coffin and the group and apply Object > Clip > Set Inverse. No group is needed if there's only one object which needs a hole under the coffin

Inverted clipping path deletes nothing, it  makes a part transparent.

BTW you are an exceptional XY questioner, you also revealed the actual problem in a comment. The others maybe never get a solution for the actual problem because the actual but hidden Y isn't equivalent with asked X.

The presented solution doesn't solve your actual problem, it solves only the green and black circle case, Bitmap images need something else.

This does the job

[image]

Draw a path (=blue) along the edge

Insert a big rectangle (=red) between the photo and the drawn rectangle. Beware moving the path or photo.

Subtract the blue path from the rectangle (=Path > Difference)

Select the photo and the rectangle with hole, apply Object > Clip > Set

I inserted some blue garbage under the result to show there's a hole.

I guess a white cover drawn over the photo could also do the job if there's nothing else under the photo than white.

GIMP is the tool for photo editing. There a hole is made in seconds when there's good contrast. The next result took 10 seconds in GIMP. The grey between the wires and surrounding white were selected with the Fuzzy selection tool (=the magic wand) and DEL was pressed:

[image]

Comment: yes, I'm an XY questioner `:)`, 
I thought the two samples were solvable in the same way, thanks for having both answers